# jQuery - var is underfined

Tags: jquery

I have following script:

```
    $('.news ul li').hide();
    $('.news ul li:first-child').show();


    function Roller() {
        var CurrectNews = $('.news ul li').filter(':visible');
        var FirstNews = $('.news ul li:first-child');

        if ( $(CurrectNews).is(':last-child') ){    
                $(CurrectNews).fadeOut('slow');
                $(FirstNews).fadeIn('slow');
           } else {
               $(CurrentNews).fadeOut('slow');
               $(CurrentNews).next().fadeIn('slow');            
        }
    }
    setInterval(Roller, 5000);
```

When I run it, FireBug is saying that `CurrentNews is underfinded`. Why?

When I watch for `$('.news ul li').filter(':visible');` it does find 1 element, as expected.

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be liberally switching between `CurrentNews` and `CurrectNews`. That might be the problem.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - its always the small things! Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your spelling:

```
CurrectNews
     ^
```

and

```
CurrentNews
     ^
```

… are different variable names.

Comment: It's answering the question though?

Comment: @jAndy — Why? It answers the question. The variable is undefined because when Dogbert tried to define it, he misspelt it.

Comment: @Quentin: I know, maybe I'm out of line about that. One liner answers feel just so comment'ish .

Comment: @Quentin- its always the small things! Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You have several typos in there. Try

```
function Roller() {
    var CurrentNews = $('.news ul li').filter(':visible');
    var FirstNews = $('.news ul li:first-child');

    if ( CurrentNews.is(':last-child') ){    
            CurrentNews.fadeOut('slow');
            FirstNews.fadeIn('slow');
       } else {
           CurrentNews.fadeOut('slow');
           CurrentNews.next().fadeIn('slow');            
    }
}
```

Comment: Add to that, take out the re-wrapping of the variables. It's unnecessary to construct another jQuery object of a jQuery object.

Comment: @Shef, ah, didn't notice that. Fixed.

Comment: @Shef - re-wrapping? Could you explain please.

Comment: @NewUser: What you have in your original code `$(CurrectNews)` is the same with `$($('.news ul li').filter(':visible'))`, do you get it now?

Comment: @shef - do you mean as is not necessary to use var?

Comment: @NewUser: Nope, I mean you don't need to construct a jQuery object out of the jQuery object which is stored in the `CurrentNews`. You just access it directly. See the difference between the code on the answer and yours, and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: @shef - ohhh... I have not noticed that before! I have been using double wrapping for months now! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may have a typo:

```
if ( $(CurrectNews).is(':last-child') ){    
            $(CurrectNews).fadeOut('slow');
            $(FirstNews).fadeIn('slow');
       } else {
           $(CurrentNews).fadeOut('slow');
           $(CurrentNews).next().fadeIn('slow');            
    }
```

The first two instances of `CurrentNews` are in fact `CurrectNews`. This may cause the problem

EDIT: Quentin got there first :)